# How to update toolbar when is store is got updated

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am trying to load a store by overriding start and page parameters in my search criteria action.

```
 store.load({
 scope:store,
 params:{
        start:0,
        limit:10,
        page:1,
        searchCriterial:mysearchobject

        },
 callBack:function(){

                  }

 })
```

By above code I am able to load the store  ,But when i try to load the store in the page 2 with above load method the data is getting loaded but toolbar is showing still page 2 . I want to update the paging toolbar when I load the store with page 1.

I have tried loadPage method in paging toolbar but it is taking another store service call.

How to change the page number in the paging toolbar or reset the toolbar to page 1

Answer (score 0):

The ExtJs paging toolbar uses the `pageSize: itemsPerPage` and start/limit params to calculate paging properties.

From the code provided you should just need to specifiy the pageSize parameter on your store, like so:

```
var itemsPerPage = 2;   // set the number of items you want per page

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id:'simpsonsStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    pageSize: itemsPerPage, // items per page
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'pagingstore.js',  // url that will load data with respect to start and limit params
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});

// specify segment of data you want to load using params
store.load({
    params:{
        start:0,
        limit: itemsPerPage
    }
});
```